# Function in SQL update query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have used function substr in my sql query:

```
UPDATE staff 
   SET dept_id='".$department."', 
       SUBSTR(auth, 0, 1) = 'l' 
 WHERE staffid='".$name."'
```

...but query fails:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'SUBSTR(auth, 0, 1)='l' WHERE staffid='55000010''` at line 1

I wish to replace first 0th charater upto length 1 of auth column to value 'l'

Comment: What exactly do you want to set? `UPDATE table SET FUNCTION() = value` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I want to set auth columns element at postition 0 to length 1 ='l'.

Comment: Your code is not SQL. It's s mixture of SQL and PHP code.

Comment: Your server is going to be hacked. Google for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you are attempting to replace the first character of the auth field with a l - although it is not entirely clear from your post if that is the intention, or just to prefix it.

```
UPDATE staff set dept_id='".$department."', auth=concat('l',SUBSTR(auth, 2))
WHERE staffid='".$name."'
```

Comment: I wish to replace first 0th charater upto length 1 to value 'l'

Comment: the technique is to not attempt a single replace like you tried, but you replace the entiure auth with a new value, constructed from 'l' + the remainder of the auth string from position 1 onwards

Comment: Can u give me good idea to do so...

Comment: Does it replace only mentioned position character?

Comment: yes, look up concat, substr and understand the logic being suggested here, then test it on some test data - you will be better off for understanding it, then just accepting it as working - this is pretty basic SQL.

Comment: Wat would I do if I wish to replace 10th position?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5160/discussion-between-andrew-and-rahul-singh)

Comment: SUBSTR() start at 1th character, there is no 0 for mysql substr

Answer (score 0):

```
example auth = "asd"
result auth = "lsd"


1. Reads auth value from 2nd character to last
2. Merge 'l' with readed value
3. Set new auth that merged value
```

#### SQL

```
UPDATE staff 
SET dept_id='".$department."', 
    auth = CONCAT('l',SUBSTR(auth, 2)) 
WHERE staffid='".$name."
```